# csurf with React: Invalid token after changing user

Tags: reactjs, csrf, csrf-token

I've had csrf protection with the csurf module working for a while now on my React SPA. I am also using passport for authentication. I do not do any server-side rendering, so the server sends a csrf token in the response body to the client when it hits the /users/current endpoint, which is protected with csrfProtection, something like this:

```
import csrf from 'csurf';
const csrfProtection = csrf();

router.get("users/current", csrfProtection, async function(req, res)
{
  .....
  res.write(JSON.stringify({ ..., csrfToken: req.csrfToken() }));
  res.end();
}
```

On the client side I then add the token to all subsequent request headers, a bit like this:

```
axiosInstance.get("/users/current")
  .then(resJson => 
  {
    axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config =>
    {
      config.headers["x-csrf-token"] = resJson.data.csrfToken;
      return config;
    });
  }
```

My first question is how the first request even manages to pass the csrfProtection without a token in its header. Yet since the token can only be accessed on the server to send to the client if the route is csrf protected, I don't see a way around this, and it does work somehow.

However, recently I have been getting "ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token" when a user logs in or deletes their account. This has only started happening after I upgraded all my node packages to the latest versions. First the client makes a request to /users/login to submit the username & password, and then makes a request to /users/current to get the new csrf token:

```
axiosInstance.post("/users/login", {
    "username": login.username,
    "password": login.password
   })
   .then(async resJson =>
   {
      // *code to update user details in redux store*
      // ......

      axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config =>
      {
        config.headers["x-csrf-token"] = undefined;
        return config;
      });

      return resJson;
   })
   .then(async resJson => 
   {
      const { csrfToken } = await axiosInstance.get("/users/current")
        .then(resJson => resJson.data);

      axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config =>
      {
        config.headers["x-csrf-token"] = csrfToken;
        return config;
      });

      return resJson.data;
   }
```

I suspect it's something to do with subsequent requests coming from a different userId (which I obtain from req.user[0].userId), with which csurf will not accept the previously issued token. But I have no idea how to issue the new token csurf does expect, to the client. And it still doesn't explain why what I had before has suddenly stopped working since none of my logic has changed. This isn't the kind of error I'd typically expect after package updates.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/9cbp7t/noob_confusion_around_expressreact_csrf_protection/) someone mentions you can just set any header on the client and have the server check for that. atm I am adding the csrf token to all the client's request headers and using the csurf module's request handler function to check it, but there is nothing stopping me from writing my own. If this is true, the value of the header doesn't even matter, just that it exists. I am holding off on this option though because I feel there is something basic I'm not understanding about my current setup, which once rectified will mean this can be easily fixed.

Would appreciate any help or explanation! Thanks

Comment: The response to the first request has the CSRF token in its body (`res.write(... req.csrfToken() ...)`), not in a header. And this token may be bound to a session cookie, so that it becomes invalid when the session changes after user login or logout.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen yep, the csrf token in the response body is what I intended, just as a way to get it sent to the client. Then I meant to say "client side I then add the token to all subsequent request headers" but I wrote "response" by accident - will fix that now to avoid further confusion.

Comment: That would make sense that it is bound to the session. But with the csurf module I'm not sure how to access the new token associated with the new session so I can send it to the client.

Comment: Your client must obtain a fresh token after a new session has been established (for example, after a user switch). In your case, this means a fresh `GET /users/current` request.

Comment: Ok, have finally gotten around to trying that again! Still no luck. The client requests & receives the new csrfToken from /users/current after successful login and uses this to update the token in the http header, but any subsequent requests for user data with this updated token are still flagged by csurf as 'invalid csrf token' and the request fails.

Comment: Can you update the question with your latest code?

Comment: I also tried clearing the token from the http header before sending the req to /users/current, in case that helps csurf to associate the new token it generates with the current user session (of the user that's just logged in). Also didn't help

Comment: I've added a second code block in my question to show my updated client code :)